# RxJava: protect an existing API method from excessive async calls by users by `debouncing()`

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Let's say I have an instance singleton class with a very popular method `paint()`:

```
public MyClass {
    public void paint() {
        // repaint the screen
    };
}
```

Code from all over the place calls this `paint()` method at unspecified times asynchronously. E.g. there's a timer that periodically calls that method, every time a user clicks a mouse button in an app it gets called, etc.
I want to convert this direct call of `paint()` by user code to something that produces an `Observable` that I could `debounce()`. Something like:

```
public MyClass {
    Observable<PaintRequest> obs;

    private init() {
        obs = (???).debounce(N ms).subscribe(e -> {
            actuallyPaint();
        });
    }
    public void paint() {
        // push an event into an Observable somehow?
    }
    private void actuallyPaint() {...}
}
```

Can't wrap my head around the design.

Comment: Your example is confusing because that's not how UI toolkits work. User code doesn't call `paint()` or the equivalent; it marks things dirty and the framework calls `paint()`. (There might even be frameworks where the method that marks things dirty is called `paint()`, but in that case `paint()` is lightweight and you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Replace paint() with any other method, it's not a specific example. Compute() would work. The point is - I have a method that various pieces of code can call at random times. I want to proxy that method so that I can throttle invocations. User code is allowed to "ring the bell" as often as they please, I just want to react to that only once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PublishRelay`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay) is quite a good candidate to achieve the requested functionality. Relay is both observer and provider, so you can listen to values and push values via the `accept()` method. Method `hide()` hides relay implementation from a consumer, and he sees only plain `Observable`.

```java
class MyClass {

    private final PublishRelay<Integer> paintedRelay = PublishRelay.create();

    public void paint() {
        // paint to canvas

        // notify observers
        paintedRelay.accept(0);
    }

    public Observable<Integer> getPaintedNotifier() {
        return paintedRelay.hide();
    }
}

public class SO64938709Test {

    @Test
    public void whenPaintedThenNotified() {
        MyClass tested = new MyClass();

        TestObserver<Integer> testObserver = tested.getPaintedNotifier().test();

        tested.paint();

        testObserver.assertValueCount(1);
    }
}
```